# IdentityDbContext making too many connections it seems

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.0, azure-appservice

I'm using `IdentityDbContext` in an Azure App Service application (.NET 4.7.1) and I use Unity to inject it in controllers and other class constructors.

Here's how it is configured in Unity

```
container.RegisterType<DbContext, ApplicationDbContext>(new Unity.AspNet.Mvc.PerRequestLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>>(new Unity.AspNet.Mvc.PerRequestLifetimeManager());

 
container.RegisterType(typeof(IUserStore<ApplicationUser>), typeof(UserStore<ApplicationUser>), new Unity.AspNet.Mvc.PerRequestLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>(new Unity.AspNet.Mvc.PerRequestLifetimeManager());
```

So I think I got this right, I want a new instance created for every request hitting my API.

`ApplicationUserManager` is injected into a base class controller which dozens of other controllers inherit from.

As far as I know, Entity Framework has a pool of connections and choose to either reuse or open a connection so that shouldn't be an issue.

Here's the problem though. In Azure I suddenly started getting a notice how outbound connections were exhausted, I had to upgrade to a `B2` service plan, something I never needed to do before.

Here's what the portal is telling me:

[image]

The IP crossed out in red is the connection for the SQL Identity Database. Is this a normal amount of connections for this case ?

Is my Unity config faulty and making Entity Framework make more connections than it should ?